# Number of Solutions of $y^2-6y+2x^2+8x=367$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

Find the number of solutions in integers to the equation

$$y^2-6y+2x^2+8x=367$$

How should I go about solving this?

Thanks!

Comment: $$y^2-6y=(y-3
)^2-9 \\2x^2+8x=2(x^2+4x)=2((x+2)^2-4)\\
(y-3)^2-9+2(x+2)^2-8=367 $$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the completing the square technique to get $(y-3)^2+2(x+2)^2 = 384$.

Make the substitution $a = y-3$ and $b = x+2$ to get $a^2+2b^2 = 384$.

Since $2b^2$ and $384$ are even, $a^2$ must be even, and hence $a$ is even. So let $a = 2a_1$.

Then, we get $4a_1^2+2b^2 = 384$, i.e. $2a_1^2+b^2 = 192$.

Since $2a_1^2$ and $192$ are even, $b^2$ must be even, and hence $b$ is even. So let $b = 2b_1$.

You can keep doing this until you get down to $2a_4^2+b_3^2 = 3$.

Then, its easy to find all solutions and undo all the substitutions.

Comment: Just because $a^2$ is even does not mean $a$ is a multiple of $4$. Try $a = 2$ for example.

Comment: Gotcha, that makes sense; thanks.

Comment: Your technique is fine, but it is (very) time consuming if you have to divide by $2$ about $10$ times.

Comment: Yes, but after the first two times, it is easy to see the pattern. Also, seeing that $384 = 3 \cdot 128 = 3 \cdot 2^7$ helps.

Answer (score 2):

$(y-3)^2 + 2(x+2)^2 = 384 \Rightarrow (x+2)^2 \leq 192 \Rightarrow |x+2| \leq \sqrt{192} = 13.85 \Rightarrow |x+2| = 0,1,\cdots,13$. You can take it from here.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** this  method requires basic knowledge of conic sections.

First of all it is equation of an ellipse,

[image]

And its vertex are $(-2,3-8\sqrt6)|(-2,3+8\sqrt6) \approx(-2,-16.6)|(-2,22.6)$

So, you can vary $y$ from $-16$ to $22$ and you will get all integral solutions.